# Discrete binary search

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

Can someone please explain [discrete binary search](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binarySearch) with an example?

I read about it on the above link, and got a basic idea about what it is, but I still don't understand the code part and how it is practically implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, assume that

- You have a function f(x) which is monotonically increasing
  (decreasing) on the interval [a, b].
- f(a) < C < f(b)
- You want to find x such that f(x) = C.

Then you can use binary search to find x. Essentially, you half the possible interval for the variable `x` each time.

To implement it, do something along the lines of:

```
#define EPS 1E-9

double f(double x)
{
   ///some monotonically increasing function on [a, b], for example f(x) = x^3:
   return x*x*x;
}

double binarySearch(double C, double a, double b)
{
   double low = a, high = b;
   double mid;
   while(abs(low-high) > EPS)
   {
      mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
      if f(mid) < C
          low = mid;
      else
          high = mid;
   }
   return mid;
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, it makes the code shorter and easier to understand.

Comment: For you, okay, but what about someone less experienced that doesn't know what epsilon is?

Comment: Just to check if i got this right: Binary search is used for finding an element in a sorted array which is just a function,given interval (a,b). Discrete binary search uses the same idea/logic but not necessarily an array,but any monotonic function. Is it all..?

Comment: Yes, that's essentially it.

Comment: @Leonardo, I defined epsilon, so I assume that you refer to the concept. I still think that the intuitive way that the continuous case can be understood is much easier to explain than the discrete case. Then you never have to deal with off-by-one issues. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: @riklund Thanks.. but i cannot up vote your answer(not many reputations) :P

Comment: is it possible that your while-condition should be the other way around? `... > EPS`

Comment: So binary search finds an element in a _discrete_ set while discrete binary search finds an element in a _continuous_ set. I'm sure this makes sense somehow (not to me though).